# Link object data to extrude multiple meshes but then have "extrusions" merge in same place as opposed to origin

Tags: modeling, objects, linked-data

just trying a proof of principle.

i have 3 cubes which are subdivided. linked object data so that when i extrude some faces on one cube they all extrude in parallel.

However, i actually would like the extruded faces to all aim towards and converge on one point.  is this possible?

(in the long run, i'm trying recreate Up baloon scene).[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you link all objects to the same mesh, they have to look the same before the modifier stack is applied. So question is what kind of a modifier you want to use for that. One possibility is a Hook modifier, which you can easily add in Edit Mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> shortcut:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back so quickly.  that's spot on.

Comment: @BuddingBlenderer I don't like asking for points, but marking the answer as accepted will help other users of the site - cheers!

Comment: apologies for that.. didn't realise that was a thing! hopefully done now